# EC2 Ping is working, but not TCP socket

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, tcp

I have created an EC2 instance and started a Socket Server in that instance. From the client I'm able to ping but from the JAVA client the socket is not connecting.
I have set security group's inbound and outbound as "All Traffic"
Operating system is Windows Server 2012 and client is Windows 10.

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: Getting connection timeout exception, if i place both in VM with localhost as IP, it works fine.

Comment: Almost sure this is firewall-related. Either your cluster's security config, or your Windows server's.

Comment: Indeed it was a firewall issue, I have just created TCP rule with appropriate port. Please make your comment in the Answer section, so I'll make it as an answer. It may help others as well.